# Re-order Odoo applications in switcher

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

Hello I want to change the order of the application in odoo version 13 is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible each app has a sequence which can be changed, for example the Discuss application has 1 in the sequence and that's why it appears 1st in the switcher, to re-order your apps:

- Activate developer mode
- Go: Settings => Technical => User Interface => Menu Items
- Search for the app that you want
- Change the sequence to whatever position